# Adjusting vertical spacing between composer and arranger

Tags: lilypond

I'm looking for a way to adjust the vertical space that's present between the composer and arranger.

Here's an example of some code that demonstrates this:

```
\version "2.22.1"

\header {
  title = "My Title"
  composer = \markup \box { \small "Composed by Some Guy" }
  arranger = \markup \box { \small "Arranged by The Arranger" }
  tagline = ##f
}

\score {
  \new Staff \relative c' {
    c d e
  }
}
```

I've surrounded both the composer and arranger with a box to make the space more obvious:

[image]

As you can see, there's some vertical space betewen both items which I wish to either eliminate or minimise.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first step in these kind of problems is usually to run your input with `annotate-spacing = ##t`.

Comment: Lol, when I read the headline I seriously thought this was about levitating individual humans. "Do I have enough 'distance from the source material' *now*?"

Comment: @AndyBonner - Question: How do you increase vertical space between a composer and an arranger? Answer: Kill one of ’em! <cue laughter>

Answer (score 4):

Well it took me a little while to figure this out, but it seems that you can customise the way headings are displayed by overriding `bookTitleMarkup`.  The trick to removing vertical space between elements is with the use of `\override #'(baseline-skip . <amount>)`.

This is what I ended up with:

```
...
\paper {
  #(define fonts
    (set-global-fonts
      #:roman "Academico")
  )

  indent = 20

  bookTitleMarkup = \markup {
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 3.5)
    \column {
      \override #'(baseline-skip . 3.5)
      \column {
        \fill-line {
          \huge \larger \larger
          \fromproperty #'header:title
        }
        \fill-line {
          \fromproperty #'header:subtitle
        }
      }
      \vspace #1
      \override #'(baseline-skip . 2)
      \column {
        \fill-line {
          \null
          \smaller \concat { "Composed by " \fromproperty #'header:composer }
        }
        \fill-line {
          \null
          \smaller \concat { "Arranged by " \fromproperty #'header:arranger }
        }
      }
      \vspace #0.5
    }
  }
}
...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: P.S.: The default configuration for `bookTitleMarkup` may be found under **/usr/share/lilypond/current/ly/titling-init.ly**.